# Download artifacts from Maven repository without using Maven

Tags: shell, maven, wget, artifactory, nexus

In various shell scripts, we need to download artifacts from a Maven repository (Nexus 2.x at the moment, but may change in the future).

The servers that run the scripts usually have no Maven installed. So I am looking for something http based.

On the one hand, there is a REST interface which can be used like

```
wget "http://local:8081/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?g=com.mycompany&a=some-app&v=1.2.3"
```

On the other hand, you can construct a "standard" URL that seems to work for different Maven repositories. It consists of a prefix, then the groupId with slashes instead of dots, then the artifactId, then the version and then a file name of the form `artifactId-(classifier)-version.type`.

What is the recommended practise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Maven coordinates section of the POM reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates) describes the second scenario you mentioned. In general I've found that pattern easiest to explain to folks learning Maven, i.e. whether local or remote, an artifact is located at

```
$REPO/groupId/as/path/artifactId/version/artifactId-version[-classifier].type
```

where $REPO can be `$USER_HOME/.m2/repository` or `https://remote.repo:port/...`.

I would also prefer the second as I suspect it will be easier for this app to work with another repository some day if needed. Even if not quite true, it's more self-documenting, so seems like it would be easier to adjust.

Comment: Maybe I confused you with my question, but I think the classifier comes last, i.e. after the version. Furthermore, the version is missing in the path. Thank you very much for the link and the explanation.

Comment: Good call outs, indeed I was looking at how you typed the filename in your question when I answered. And I just missed the version. Fixed now. Glad it helps!